# EF.Functions.Contains including multiple keywords

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to search on multiple columns (LearningModuleDesc and LearningModuleContent which works using the || statements below) but I also need to search on multiple keywords. .Net Core 2.2 and EF Core does not support the string array with Contains (like the example below) but some guidance of how I would go about this would be great.

```
string[] stringarray = new string[] { "mill", "smith" };

var results =  _context.LearningModules
.Where(x => EF.Functions.Contains(x.LearningModuleDesc, stringarray)
|| EF.Functions.Contains(x.LearningModuleContent, stringarray)
);
```

Answer (score -8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for something like this

```
 var results = _context.LearningModules.Where(
   x => stringarray.Any(t => x.LearningModuleDesc.Contains(t)) || 
        stringarray.Any(t => x.LearningModuleContent.Contains(t)))
```

Comment: This doesn't translate to SQL though and executes locally.

Comment: @Ivan [Can't wait...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client).

Comment: @Gert Wow (finally they get there!), me too :)

Comment: Question is about Full Text CONTAINS function, not string contains.